# Cointegration in R: Which regressions are performed in `urca::ca.jorls` and how does the output differ from `urca::ca.jo`?

Tags: r, time-series, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

In `cajorls` function from `urca` package a series of OLS is performed. From the documentation:

> This function returns the OLS regressions of a restricted VECM, i.e. it returns a list object with elements of class ‘lm’ containing the restricted VECM and a matrix object with the normalised cointegrating relationships. The user can provide a certain number of which equation in the VECM should be estimated and reported, or if "reg.number = NULL" each equation in the VECM will be estimated and its results are reported. Furthermore, the cointegratioon rank has to be supplied too.

The input is object of class `ca.jo`. **My question is: what are they regressing on what?**

The VECM is
$$
\Delta Y_t = \alpha\beta^T Y_{t-1} + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\Gamma_i\Delta Y_{t-i}+\mu  +\epsilon_t
$$

As far as I know $\alpha,\beta $ is already estimated in `ca.jo`, right? (I think this is where I go wrong with the understanding of the model.) How does the $\alpha$'s and $\beta$'s in this regression differ from the ones in `ca.jo`? Basically what I want is someone explain how the regression equations look exactly.

The output of the function is $\beta$ and $\Gamma_i$'s. I can't find $\alpha$. Also, I assume `ECT` stands for error correction term? How does this term connect with the VECM from above?

This question is related [VECM - interpreting output from cajorls()](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354789/vecm-interpreting-output-from-cajorls) but unfortunately it does not have a thorough answer